# Extracting Climate classifications from raster using multiple polygon shapefiles

Tags: arcgis-desktop, clip, extract-by-mask

I have performed a cluster analysis on geographic locations (national and sub-national level) in Matlab.  I have also written code to write the shapefiles for each of the locations in a cluster to it's own folder.

Using the Köppen classification found [here](https://www.nature.com/articles/sdata2018214), I have added this raster to ArcGIS 10.2.2, such that each pixel is a value between zero and thirty. I then add all of my shapefiles from the specified folder.

I want to produce a table that gives me the name of the country/region (which is in the polygon shapefiles) along with the Köppen classifications that were found within that region.

I started by merging all the shapefiles into one and then tried a number of different routes:

- I did a raster clip using my new shpefile to clip the raster and then created an attribute table for the raster.
- I have tried converting the raster to a polygon after clipping it and creating a spatial join.
- I also tried an 'extract by mask' using the 'feature outline masks' tool to convert the raster clip to a mask.

Each time I try something I end up with either:

(1) An attribute table that has no region names, but does have the Koppen number/code along with a count of the number of times the Koppen code occurs. This is, I assume, a count of the number of gridcells with that classication.

or

(2) A table with the shape lengh and area of polygons, along with the classification code.
I havent been able to produce an attribute table showing the name of the region, along with the Koppen classification number(s) for that region (one region can have more than one classification). I don't want counts, just to know what regions are found within each country/region.

Any suggestions?